# How to put movie clip, video or animation to my android project

Tags: android, eclipse, media-player, movie

I'm new in making android projects and my group mates and I need to learn how to put movie clips, videos or animations to our android project. We are using eclipse indigo.

Answer (score 0):

Specifically if this is preloaded content then you can load it into your application by actually adding this content into the assets folder of your project.

As for animations, this is a case by case situation, but most likely you're going to have to get your animations working using the android animation frameworks.

Also instead of just **ASKING FOR THE ANSWER** try doing some research. Its your thesis after all.